# Setting the fill pattern on a custom conditional rule in a javascript Excel add-in

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

Is there a way to set the fill pattern in conditional format using excel-js add-in?

No problem to set the conditional format fill color but I can not find any properties to set the fill pattern style or the fill pattern color.

[image: Intellisense of fill properties]

Is there any way to around that? (I'm thinking something similar to setting valuesAsJSON...)